# Why do I have to address different browsers with a prefix for the same css?

Tags: html, css

I am curious, as to why some browsers need a special invitation for the same css layout command.
Can anyone enlighten me?

Example: CSS-formatting:
box-sizing: border-box; (Please consider the border of my box for dimensions!)

Now here come firefox and safari, and they need a special invitation:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

To a simple cat like myself this seems like saying:

1. Browsers: The dimensions I gave you count for the borders of my box!
2. firefox: This also counts for you.
3. Safari: It goes for you as well.

I mean... why? It is exactly the same syntax! Why do I have to tell the same stuff to a specific browser? I would understand if they need a different syntax.. but exactly the same?! Do they like to hear their names being called?

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of different browser engines supporting different things. Those directives simply are aimed at telling the browser's rendering engines that you are looking to use a feature that is still in development/testing or not standard in the CSS specification. Note that not all browsers use different rendering engines.

Answer (score 1):

because these properties are not starndardized by the W3C, they are still in draft, therefore vendors implement their own version - that uses prefixes to avoid clashes with other browsers implementation, or the final implementation after the specs are finalized.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, at first each of the browser manufacturers decided a css style would be a good idea, but there was no standard for it. Each browser manufacturer added the css style their way with their prefix. Eventually, most of these styles have become CSS3 standards (usually based on what the browser manufacturers were already doing), but since the older browsers did not support the CSS3 standard (only their standard with their prefix) we still have ro put each browser's syntax/prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Though I wonder... wouldn't life be much easier, if whatever browser finds a command it knows... it just tries to execute it? Prefixed or not?

Comment: It might be easier, but the earlier browsers don't know how the official style will be defined, so if they were to try to interpret the non-prefixed one, thy might interpret it wrong, which would make it even worse than if it didn't try to interpret it at all.

Answer (score 0):

it means that this functions are still under development and may not support every functionality which the standard dictates

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the above answers. When you list all properties, list the standard property last, like so:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px 5px;
-webkit-boder-radius: 10px 5px;
border-radius: 10px 5px;
```

If you do it this way, an old Firefox will use the first rule and ignore the others because it doesn't understand them, the same for an old Safari.

The problems comes with recent versions of the browsers, which support `border-radius` without a prefix, when you list the standard property first:

```
border-radius: 10px 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px 5px;
-webkit-boder-radius: 10px 5px;
```

When you browse this site in Safari, it will first use the standard property and then override it with the `-webkit-` property. The problem is that the specifications for the two implementations are different. The *standard property* makes the top left and bottom right corner 30px-rounded and top right and bottom left 10px-rounded.

On the other hand, the *-webkit-prefixed* property makes all corner the same: an ellipsis with size 30x10px.